# What's the maximum number of parameters you can add to a Google App Engine task?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

```
TaskOptions taskOptions = TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/mytask");
options.param("a", a);
options.param("b", b);
options.param("c", c);
options.param("d", d);
options.param("e", e);
options.param("f", f);
options.param("g", g);
options.param("a1", a1);
options.param("b1", b1);
options.param("c1", c1);
options.param("d1", d1);
options.param("e1", e1);
options.param("f1", f1);
options.param("g1", g1);
```

How many options params can I specify here? Is there an upper limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [release notes for version 1.5.0 of the SDK](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.5.0_-_May_10,_2011) say the following:

> Task Queue payload limits have been increased. Queues support 100KB per task.

The [QueueConstants class](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/QueueConstants.html) has a `maxPushTaskSizeBytes()` method which you can call to get the size.

The [source code for QueueConstats.java](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/QueueConstants.java) confirms the limit to be 100k:

```
private static final int MAX_PUSH_TASK_SIZE_BYTES = 100 * (1 << 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine that there is a hard upper-limit at the maximum amount of memory allocated to your JVM instance, which may be anywhere between a few dozen to a few hundred MB.

Prior to hitting that limit, there may be platform/client specific limitations on the size, since you are basically constructing an HTTP GET or POST request (depending upon how you have set up your `TaskOptions`).  The client that ultimately processes the request [may have its own limits on size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url).

But even in the worst-case scenario you should be able to pass at least 2 KB worth of data using a GET format URL/request (regardless of whether it is distributed across many parameters or just one).  That would be if App Engine inexplicably uses the same request processing code as Internet Explorer.  I think it's very likely that the Google code can handle quite a bit more than that.

And why not just try it and see?  Just write a loop that queues up increasingly long tasks until it eventually fails, and log out the size of the request that triggers the failure.